# Are Laravel abilities polymorphic on the argument?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My understanding is that abilities defined using policies are indeed **polymorphic**, meaning that:

```
Gate::allows('update', $post);
Gate::allows('update', $comment);
```

will call different functions, if the two objects are of different classes, that are registered with different policies:

```
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    Comment::class => CommentPolicy::class,
];
```

While it seems to me that abilities defined using `$gate->define()` are **not polymorphic**, meaning that two invocations using the same policy name will overwrite each other:

```
$gate->define('update', function ($user, $post)    { /* THIS IS THROWN AWAY! */ });
$gate->define('update', function ($user, $comment) { /* the last one is kept */ });
```

Is this correct?

Is there any relationship between the ability names shown in the documentation for the non-polymorphic examples (`update-post`, `update-comment`) and those shown in the policy examples (`update`)?

I mean, is the `-post` suffix added or inferred by Laravel? Or is it just an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a notable difference between policy defined abilities and gate defined abilities.

- When you use the `define` method of the gate, your ability name will be [added to the abilities array of the gate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L97-L108) with the array key being the ability name. If you define another ability with the same name (e.g. `update`), it will override the old one since there can't be two array keys with the same name. So in this case the unique identifier in `define($ability, $callback)` is the ability.
- Conversely, when you define a policy class, the abilities names are the actual method names of the policy. So you can have multiple classes with methods named the same (e.g. `update`), because in this case the unique identifier is the class passed with the first argument, so `Post::class`.

At some point during the authorization check, the Gate class checks [if there's a policy associated with the first argument passed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L319-L320) and calls a policy method or a defined ability callback based on that evaluation.

So the idea is that you can't have two abilities with the same name when using `define` because the below is not possible:

```
$abilities = [
    'update' => $callback1,
    'update' => $callback2, // this will override the first
]
```

Just as when using `$policies` you can't associate more than one policy to a class:

```
$policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    Post::class => AnotherPostPolicy::class, // this will override the first one
];
```

So if you like to use `update` as an ability name for more than one model, just use policies.

This should also answer you final question: Laravel doesn't infer or add anything, the ability names are either strings you pass to `define` or method names you define on policy classes.